# How to solve this Geometric Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I believe this is a geometric series and that is all the problem stated.

If $0 < x < 1$, find $f(x) = 1 + x +  x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + \cdots$

Comment: What have you tried? do you know any formulas associated with a geometric series?

Comment: Yes please review the geometric series and formulas associated with them. A great place to start is on Wolfram's Mathworld.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_n=1+x+\cdots+x^n$, then

$$S_n-xS_n=(1+x+\cdots+x^n)-(x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n+1})=1-x^{n+1}$$

or

$$(1-x)S_n=1-x^{n+1}$$

So,
$$S_n={1-x^{n+1}\over 1-x}.$$

Now $$1+x+x^2+\cdots=\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}{1-x^{n+1}\over 1-x}=\frac1{1-x}.$$

The last equality holds because $0<x<1$ implies $x^{n+1}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I completely forgot about the left side of the equation so I was stuck after 1-x^(n+1). Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

$x F(x)  = F(x) -1$ so

$F(x) = (1-x)^{-1}.$

More rigorously, use the formula for a geometric series and let the number of terms go to infinity.